# Cannot import BrowserService from charm-down

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I want use the gluon charm plugin in my JavaFX app to get the BrowserService, to open a webpage natively.

I followed the steps as per their documentations here:
http://gluonhq.com/gluon-mobile-4-0-0-now-available/

But, when I try to import the BrowseRService under com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins, I cannot. It only gives me options for Lifecyle, Storage, display, statusbar services.

But I do see the browser service code in the external libraries.

This is my corresponding build.gradle code

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0'
}

jfxmobile {
        downConfig {
            version '3.1.0'
            plugins 'browser'
        }
        android {
            manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        ios {
            infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
            forceLinkClasses = [
                    'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                    'javax.annotations.**.*',
                    'javax.inject.**.*',
                    'javax.json.**.*',
                    'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
            ]
        }
    }
```

Anything Im missing?

Comment: Have you checked your dependencies? Once you add a new plugin refresh your gradle project and check under Runtime for Android and/or iOS, you should find the `charm-down-plugin-browser-*-3.1.0.jar`.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! Adding the dependency solved the problem. But isn't the whole process ambiguous as I need to add the dependency + have it in the down config ?

Comment: The jfxmobile plugin does it for you. Check you have the latest version (1.3.2). If you add the plugin to `downConfig` you don't need to add the dependency.